# Reading 14 bytes of factory calibration for the TM8801 in the ESP32

Tags: c, esp32, i2c, firmware

I have been having issues reading back 14 bytes of factory calibration in the TMF8001. I am currently using an ESP32 to program it.

*This is that the datasheet says to do:*

The factory calibration sequence is started by issuing to the following command to the TMF8X0X:

**S 41 W 10 0A P**

After this factory calibration is started. You can wait for the interrupt to get triggered, or poll the register 0x1E until it reads back as 0x0A:

**S 41 W 1e Sr 41 R A N P**

or have to wait a maximum time of 2 seconds.

Now read back and store the 14 bytes of factory calibration.

**S 41 W 20 Sr 41 R A A A A A A A A A A A A A N P**

*This is what I've been trying:*

```
   //Factory calibration 
    i2c_master_start(meas_read17_cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read17_cmd, (0x41 << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read17_cmd, 0x10, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read17_cmd, 0x0A, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_stop(meas_read17_cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, meas_read17_cmd, 1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(meas_read17_cmd);
    printf("TOF ret 17: %02x\n", ret);  

    vTaskDelay(5000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // wait 100ms for measurement to complete

    //Polling 0x1E register until it reads back 0x0A
    i2c_master_start(meas_read20_cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read20_cmd, (0x41 << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read20_cmd, 0x1E, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_start(meas_read20_cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read20_cmd, (0x41 << 1) | READ_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read20_cmd, poll_register_2, NACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_stop(meas_read20_cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, meas_read20_cmd, 1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(meas_read20_cmd);
    printf("TOF ret 20: %02x\n", ret);    

    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // wait 100ms for measurement to complete

    //Read back and store 14 bytes of factory calibration
    i2c_master_start(meas_read19_cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read19_cmd, (0x41 << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read19_cmd, 0x20, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_start(meas_read19_cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(meas_read19_cmd, (0x41 << 1) | READ_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_1, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_2, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_3, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_4, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_5, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_6, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_7, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_8, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_9, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_10, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_11, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_12, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_13, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(meas_read19_cmd, reg4_14, NACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_stop(meas_read19_cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, meas_read19_cmd, 1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(meas_read19_cmd);
    printf("TOF ret 19: %02x\n", ret);    

    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // wait 100ms for measurement to complete
```

This is the output in my terminal:

```
BOOT 14: c0
TOF POLL REGISTER 1 (EXP 0x41): 41
TOF POLL REGISTER 2 (EXP 0x0A): 00
REG4_1: 00
REG4_2: 00
REG4_3: 00
REG4_4: 00
REG4_5: 00
REG4_6: 00
REG4_7: 00
REG4_8: 00
REG4_9: 00
REG4_10: 00
REG4_11: 00
REG4_12: 00
REG4_13: 00
REG4_14: 00
```

Any help will be greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to copy and paste the output rather than embedding an image. Images aren't searchable and won't be handled by screen readers. The same with the data sheet. It's text, paste it in, don't use an screen cap.

Comment: @romkey thank you for the feedback, I added it to the question

Comment: @hcheung the code is 1000 lines, I can send it to you if you want.  
This is how `meas_read17_cmd` is created: 
----
 `i2c_cmd_handle_t meas_read17_cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();`  
----
`meas_read17_cmd` is not the issue